# How to change SBT's rules on generating URLs for Maven repositories?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

By default, the Scala Built Tool (SBT) has a set of rules on how to generate URLs when looking up dependencies.  For example, if I have the following build file,

```
// Project settings
name := "MyProject"

version := "0.1"

organization := "com.me"

scalaVersion := "2.8.1"

// Dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.google.guava" %% "guava" % "r09"
)

// Repositories
resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
```

Then SBT attempts to find guava at the following URL,

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava_2.8.1/r09/guava_2.8.1-r09.pom
```

However, the library I'm looking for in this case isn't even made for Scala, so combining the Scala version just doesn't make sense here.  How can I tell SBT what the format is for generating URLs for use with Maven repositories?

**EDIT**

While it seems that it is possible to edit the layout like so,

```
Resolver.url("Primary Maven Repository",
    new URL("http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"))( Patterns("[organization]/[module]/[module]-[revision].[ext]") )
```

the "[module]" keyword is predefined to be the (artifact id)_(scala version) and the "[artifact]" keyword is just "ivy", leaving me back at square one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I remember "%%" appends the scala version and "%" does not. Try

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "r09"
)
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly it, though sbt v0.10.1 chooses to hide the jar deep down in ~/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/jars, but that's a different issue.  Thanks!

Comment: You can ask sbt to put the jars in ./lib_managed. Just take a look at the sbt migration guide. (I never used it so I don't know where it ist)

Comment: Already found it.  All it takes is setting,

    "retrieveManaged := true"

Answer (score 3):

Check last one paragraph (**Custom Layout**) of official `sbt` wiki [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html#Custom+Layout).

Basically SBT allows you to use this syntax:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("my-test-repo", url)( Patterns("[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]") )
```

Comment: dead link now ... :(

Comment: @OlivierGirardot thanks! I've fixed it to up-to-date version

Comment: @om-nom-nom can u give me an example how to write patterns? for eg `https://dl.bintray.com/eed3si9n/sbt-plugins/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.11/sbt_1.0.0-M4/0.14.3/ivys/ivy.xml`